# TimeSeriesShift seems broken -- is there a stable workaround?

Tags: bugs, time-series

Issue 1: Certain dates shift into the same date, leading to duplicated keys, rendering the time series unusable:

```
TimeSeriesShift[{{{2012, 5, 31}, x}, {{2012, 6, 1}, y}, {{2012, 6, 3}, z}}, {1, "Month"}] // Normal

Out: 
{{DateObject[{2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], x}, 
 {DateObject[{2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], y}, 
 {DateObject[{2012, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], z}}
```

Issue 2: It depends on the date that follows:

```
TimeSeriesShift[{{{2012, 5, 31}, x}, {{2012, 6, 1}, y}, {{2012, 6, 2}, z}}, {1, "Month"}] // Normal

Out:
{{DateObject[{2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], x}, 
 {DateObject[{2012, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], y},
 {DateObject[{2012, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], z}}
```

This is driving me nuts. Is this issue only related to "Month" or any units? Is there a stable workaround?

Comment: gets even worse: try `ts3 = TimeSeries@{{{2012, 3, 31}, x}, {{2012, 4, 1}, 
     y}, {{2012, 4, 3}, z}}; TimeSeriesShift[ts3, {-1, "Month"}] // Normal`  and
`DatePlus[#, {-1, "Month"}] & /@ ts3["Dates"]`

Comment: even worse: try `DatePlus[{2012, 3, 31}, {-1, "Month"}]` and `DatePlus[DateObject@{2012, 3, 31}, {-1, "Month"}]`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to different date arithmetic depending on the granularity of the DateObject:

```
In[157]:= 
DatePlus[#, {1, "Month"}] & /@ {{2012, 5, 31}, {2012, 6, 1}, {2012, 6, 3}}

Out[157]= {{2012, 6, 30}, {2012, 7, 1}, {2012, 7, 3}}

In[158]:= 
DatePlus[#, {1, "Month"}] & /@ (DateObject /@ {{2012, 5, 31}, {2012, 6, 1}, {2012, 6, 3}})

Out[158]= {DateObject[{2012, 7, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.], 
 DateObject[{2012, 7, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.], 
 DateObject[{2012, 7, 3}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}
```

The list input in TimeSeriesShift is converted to a TimeSeries, hence the use of DateObject under the hood. Let me think about - this maybe not the way to go for date strings...